# Create nested object of file paths

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm walking large directory tree recursively (from 100,000 to 1,000,000 objects) and need to add each file or directory to deeply nested object.

Let's assume I got file paths like

```
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
...
/pathX/file1000000
```

and I need to create following nested object based on them:

```
{
  "name": "/",
  "value": 300,
  "children": [
    { 
       "name": "/pathX",
       "value": 100,
       "children": [
       {
         "name": "/pathX/file1000000",
         "value": 100
       }
    },
    {
      "name": "/path",
      "value": 200,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "/path/to",
          "value": 200,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "/path/to/file1",
              "value": 100
            },

            {
              "name": "/path/to/file2",
              "value": 100
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `value` is a file size or sum of nested file sizes. To keep things simple, let's assume its equal to `100` for `file1`, `file2` and `fileN`.

I was able to build nested object for one file, but having issues with building it for many files with different paths:

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

let file = '/opt/bin/file1'
let size
fs.stat(file, (err, stats) => { size = stats.size })
let paths = file.split(path.sep)

let nameChild = file
let objChild = { "name" : nameChild, "value" : size }
let nameParent
let objParent

for (var i in paths) {

    if (i==0) continue

    nameParent = path.dirname(nameChild)

    objParent = { "name" : nameParent, "value" : size, "children" : [ objChild ] }

    nameChild = nameParent
    objChild = objParent

}

console.log(JSON.stringify(objParent))
```

Answer (score 2):

There you go :)

```js
function buildTree(pathes, getValueCB) {

  var currentPath, lastPath, node, parent, map = {
      "": {
        children: []
      }
    },
    stack = [""]

  for (let path of pathes) {
    let nodes = path.split("/");
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      currentPath = "/" + nodes.slice(1, i + 1).join("/")
      lastPath = stack[stack.length - 1]
      parent = map[lastPath]
      if (!map[currentPath]) {
        node = {
          name: currentPath,
          value: getValueCB(currentPath),
          children: []
        }
        parent.children.push(node);
        map[currentPath] = node;
      }
      stack.push(currentPath)
    }
    stack = stack.slice(0, 1)
  }
  return map[""].children[0];
}

function getFileSizeSync() {
  return 200
}
var tree = buildTree(["/path/to/file1", "/path/to/file2"], function(path) {
  return getFileSizeSync(path)
})

console.log (tree)
```

---

Here's the updated version that calculates the size recursively. (I can't put it into a snippet, that's why i leave the old one)

```
var fs = require('fs')
var Path = require ('path')

function calcSize (node) {
    var children = node.children; 
    node.value = children.reduce (function (size, child) {
        return size + child.value || reduceSize (child);
    }, 0)
    return node.value;
}
function getFileSizeSync(path) {
  var size = fs.statSync(path).size
  return size
}

function buildTree(pathes, getValueCB) {

  var currentPath, lastPath, node, parent, map = {
      "": {
        children: []
      }
    },
    stack = [""]

  for (let path of pathes) {
    let nodes = path.split(Path.sep);
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      currentPath = Path.sep + nodes.slice(1, i + 1).join(Path.sep)
      lastPath = stack[stack.length - 1]
      parent = map[lastPath]
      if (!map[currentPath]) {
        node = {
          name: currentPath,
          value: getFileSizeSync(currentPath),
          children: []
        }
        parent.children.push(node);
        map[currentPath] = node;
      }
      stack.push(currentPath)
    }
    stack = stack.slice(0, 1)
  }
  calcSize (map[""])
  return map[""].children[0];
}


var tree = buildTree(["/path/to/file1", "/path/to/file2"])

console.log (tree)
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point that the parent directories should *sum* the file sizes within for their values

Comment: @Jamiec Indeed!  Fixed it

Comment: @SystemsRebooter I added that part as well