# Create nested object from array of objects based on path property

Tags: typescript

I want to create a nested object, which represents a hierarchy more or less, based off a file path from an object in an array, while also including a relevant ID for that file, in Typescript.

I have an array of objects like this:

```js
interface FileInfo {
    id: string;
    path: string;
}

let files: FileInfo[] = [
  {id: '1', path: '/root/library/Folder 1/Document.docx'},
  {id: '2', path: '/root/library/Folder 1/Document 2.docx'},
  {id: '3', path: '/root/library/Folder 2/Document 3.docx'},
  {id: '4', path: '/root/library/Document 4.docx'}
];
```

Then when it is converted the desired type is:

```js
interface TreeView{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  children?: TreeView[];
}
```

- `id`:

  - If it's a folder (not last element in the path), the `id` should be something like `${name}_{uuid()}`.
  - If it's the file (final element in path), then it should take the `FileInfo.id` value.
- `name`: The current element of the path, e.g. `root`, `library` etc

So the final output would look something like:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"root_GUID",
      "name":"root",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":"library_GUID",
            "name":"library",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":"Folder 1_GUID",
                  "name":"Folder 1",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "id":"1",
                        "name":"Document.docx",
                        "children":[
                           
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "id":"2",
                        "name":"Document 2.docx",
                        "children":[
                           
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"Folder 2_GUID",
                  "name":"Folder 2",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "id":"3",
                        "name":"Document 3.docx",
                        "children":[
                           
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"4",
                  "name":"Document 4.docx",
                  "children":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Similar questions**

I've been heavily inspired by other SO posts like [Create nested object from multiple string paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679971/create-nested-object-from-multiple-string-paths) and [Create nested object of file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486462/create-nested-object-of-file-paths).

The solution outlined [in this answer from the first SO thread linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44681235/7788355) has been helpful but am stuck making it work with an object, not an array of paths and also for it to be in Typescript.

Comment: Hello @Troy,  i really appreciate your nice explication of the issue, but it would be recommend to share some parts of your code attempts so we can help you. StackOverflow is designed to resolve technical codes attempts or problematic coding concepts to be shared with others (please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to have more informations about how to ask).  Thanks

Comment: Ahh I knew I was forgetting something in my question! Thank you for the reminder @sohaiebazaiez, I had a half-working solution, though as jeremynac has provided a workable solution I will hold off on including my half-working solution and focus on his/others answers. Thank you again for the reminder, will be sure to do next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you a solution that works, and you can use it if you want.
First, one important thing (in my opinion) is to make use of recursive functions, since you're basically going recursively through your path and appending to the global tree.

```
interface FileInfo {
    id: string;
    path: string;
}

let files: FileInfo[] = [
  {id: '1', path: '/root/library/Folder 1/Document.docx'},
  {id: '2', path: '/root/library/Folder 1/Document 2.docx'},
  {id: '3', path: '/root/library/Folder 2/Document 3.docx'},
  {id: '4', path: '/root/library/Document 4.docx'}
];

interface TreeView{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    children?: TreeView[];
  }

// The main function we call, to convert a list of fileInfo to the tree
function convertPathToTreeView(fileInfos: FileInfo[]): TreeView {
    // We assume the tree starts at root, it would become very complicated otherwise because we would have no way of knowing the current depth of a path.
    let tree: TreeView = {id: 'root_uuid_here', name: 'root', children: []}
    // We go over each fileInfo and update the tree with the data contained in it.
    fileInfos.forEach((fileInfo) => {
        // We split the current path to get the file names, and we remove the leading / before splitting so we don't get '' as a first file name.
        const fileNames = fileInfo.path.replace(/^\//, "").split('/')
        tree = convertFolderOrFileToTree(tree, fileNames, fileInfo.id)
    })
    return tree
}

//This is a pretty classical recursive function, that will either return the whole tree, or append a new child to the tree by calling itself on a child of the tree.
function convertFolderOrFileToTree(currentTree: TreeView, fileNames: string[], fileId: string): TreeView {
    // This is the base case: when no more files to parse, return.
    if (!fileNames.length) {
        return currentTree;
    }
    // If the current tree name is the same as the current file name, it means that the next file in fileNames will be a child of the currentTree. (for example, if currentTree.name === root and fileNames[0] === root, we know that we are at the root, and we can consider that the next fileName will be a child of the current tree, library in this case)
    if (currentTree.name === fileNames[0]) {
        return convertFolderOrFileToTree(currentTree, fileNames.slice(1), fileId)
    } else {
        // We check if current fileName is already a child of the tree.
        const child = currentTree.children.find(t => t.name === fileNames[0]);
        if (child) {
            // If it is, we will parse the next fileName as the child of current fileName.
            return {...currentTree, children: [...currentTree.children.filter(tree => tree.name !== child.name), convertFolderOrFileToTree(child, fileNames.slice(1),fileId)]}
        } else if (fileNames.length > 1) {
            // If the fileName is not registered as a child in the tree and it's not the last fileName (meaning it's a folder), we add it and parse the other fileNames recursively
            const newTree: TreeView = {id: `${fileNames[0]}_uuid_here`, name: fileNames[0], children: []}
            return {...currentTree, children: [...currentTree.children, convertFolderOrFileToTree(newTree, fileNames.slice(1), fileId)]}
        } else {
            // If the fileName is not registered as a child in the tree and it is the last fileName, meaning it's a file, we just add it to the children and return the tree.
            const newTree: TreeView = {id: fileId, name: fileNames[0]}
            return {...currentTree, children: [...currentTree.children, newTree]}
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(convertPathToTreeView(files), null, 4))
```

Don't hesitate to ask if something is unclear, recursive functions can be a bit abstract.

If you want to allow for other roots than the /root folder, you can just specify an imaginary root, that I will call rootOfTheTree, so we can still have one tree, even if there are different roots.
You could also just have a function that returns several tree (for example if we have /root/file1 and /root2/file2), but it seems to me like that's not what you need.

Here is the code, updated, and without any warning in typescript playground (the children property can be undefined and that caused typescript to not allow just using the property without checking)

```
interface FileInfo {
    id: string;
    path: string;
}

let files: FileInfo[] = [
  {id: '1', path: '/root/library/Folder 1/Document.docx'},
  {id: '2', path: '/root/library/Folder 1/Document 2.docx'},
  {id: '3', path: '/root/library/Folder 2/Document 3.docx'},
  {id: '4', path: '/root/library/Document 4.docx'}
];

interface TreeView{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    children?: TreeView[];
  }

// The main function we call, to convert a list of fileInfo to the tree
function convertPathToTreeView(fileInfos: FileInfo[]): TreeView {
    // If we want to allow for different roots but still have one tree, we need to set a rootOfTheTree that is not a folder or a file, but just used to mark the beginning of the tree.
    let tree: TreeView = {id: 'rootOfTheTree_uuid_here', name: 'rootOfTheTree', children: []}
    // We go over each fileInfo and update the tree with the data contained in it.
    fileInfos.forEach((fileInfo) => {
        // We split the current path to get the file names, and we remove the leading / before splitting so we don't get '' as a first file name.
        const fileNames = fileInfo.path.replace(/^\//, "").split('/')
        tree = convertFolderOrFileToTree(tree, fileNames, fileInfo.id)
    })
    return tree
}

//This is a pretty classical recursive function, that will either return the whole tree, or append a new child to the tree by calling itself on a child of the tree.
function convertFolderOrFileToTree(currentTree: TreeView, fileNames: string[], fileId: string): TreeView {
    // This is the base case: when no more files to parse, return.
    if (!fileNames.length) {
        return currentTree;
    }
    // If the current tree name is the same as the current file name, it means that the next file in fileNames will be a child of the currentTree. (for example, if currentTree.name === root and fileNames[0] === root, we know that we are at the root, and we can consider that the next fileName will be a child of the current tree, library in this case)
    if (currentTree.name === fileNames[0]) {
        return convertFolderOrFileToTree(currentTree, fileNames.slice(1), fileId)
    } else {
        // We check if current fileName is already a child of the tree.
        const child = currentTree.children?.find(t => t.name === fileNames[0]);
        if (child) {
            // If it is, we will parse the next fileName as the child of current fileName.
            return {...currentTree, children: [...(currentTree.children?.filter(tree => tree.name !== child.name) ?? []), convertFolderOrFileToTree(child, fileNames.slice(1),fileId)]}
        } else if (fileNames.length > 1) {
            // If the fileName is not registered as a child in the tree and it's not the last fileName (meaning it's a folder), we add it and parse the other fileNames recursively
            const newTree: TreeView = {id: `${fileNames[0]}_uuid_here`, name: fileNames[0], children: []}
            return {...currentTree, children: [...(currentTree.children ?? []), convertFolderOrFileToTree(newTree, fileNames.slice(1), fileId)]}
        } else {
            // If the fileName is not registered as a child in the tree and it is the last fileName, meaning it's a file, we just add it to the children and return the tree.
            const newTree: TreeView = {id: fileId, name: fileNames[0]}
            return {...currentTree, children: [...(currentTree.children ?? []), newTree]}
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(convertPathToTreeView(files), null, 4))
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution thanks @jeremynac! Have tested it out and runs well. I see your comment that we assume the tree starts at `root`, how would the code differ if it wasn't always `root`? This was some sample data to illustrate the problem, in my real use cases that `root` would very likely be different. So let's assume that each `path` could have a different `root` and that it isn't always called `root`, what would need to be changed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also, when running this in Typescript Playground (link is too long to share apologies), it is listing three errors of `Object is possibly undefined` in the `convertFolderOrFileToTree` function. I tried to resolve them, but couldn't quite find a good fix for the second one.